# SQL Store result after query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query :

```
SELECT `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`Nr maszyny`
FROM `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`
INNER JOIN `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI` ON `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`id` = `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`.`Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji`
```

From this query, I get this result:

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UInQI.png)

Now I want to store this result in a new column called `test` in the table `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: After you answer the question from Jim Macaulay please answer this also: Does the column test already exist in the table KARTA URUCHOMIENIA ? Are there other columns in that same table ? How do you join this results to this other columns in that table (what is theri join connection) ?

Comment: column "test" already exist, column "Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji" is in the same table "KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI", are other 13 columns in the same table.

connection is Unique ID key from "karta zmiany formy/ wersji.id`", in the field `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`.`Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji` i have Unique ID from  table karta zmiany formy/ wersji. ex:  karta zmiany formy/ wersji.id  = 1  , `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`.`Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji` = 1

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: i tryed like that : 

ALTER TABLE `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI` CHANGE `test` `test` VARCHAR(3) AS (SELECT `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`Nr maszyny`FROM `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`INNER JOIN `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI` ON `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`id`=`KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`.`Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji`) STORED;

but i got #1064 error

Comment: @JimMacaulay I`m using  PhpmyAdmin

Comment: Its not a database, am asking about which Sql database are you using. Sql Server or Oracle or MySql?

Comment: @JimMacaulay MySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps you:

```
/*In SQLServer:*/
        update `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`
        set test=`karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`Nr maszyny`
        
        FROM `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`
        INNER JOIN `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI` 
        ON `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`id` = `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`.`Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji`
    
    /*In MYSQL:*/    
    update `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`
    INNER JOIN `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`
    ON `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`id` = `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`.`Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji`
    set test=`karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`Nr maszyny`
```

Comment: This solution is not correct. If will create new rows of data in the table or if it has primary key constraint, it will fail. The requirement is to update existing data with new value

Comment: Well, if you want to update Existing record you need  to know primary Key, and if you have; you can use `update from select`

Comment: @hesamakbari thankyou for reply, i`m not able to undestand why i got this error whit your solution :

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`
INNER JOIN `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`
O' at line 4

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
update `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI` t1
inner join (SELECT `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`.`Nr karta zmiany 
formy/wersji` as id , `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`Nr maszyny` as data FROM 
`karta zmiany formy/ wersji`
INNER JOIN `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI` ON `karta zmiany formy/ 
wersji`.`id`=`KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`.`Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji`) t2
on (t1.`KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`.`Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji` = t2.id)
set t1.test = t2.data;
```

Comment: i think MERGE is not supported by MySQL, i can use UPDATE?

Comment: i got this error :



#1054 - Unknown column 't1.KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI.Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`(test)
SELECT `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`Nr maszyny`
FROM `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`
INNER JOIN `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI` ON `karta zmiany formy/ wersji`.`id` = `KARTA URUCHOMIENIA PRODUCKJI`.`Nr karta zmiany formy/wersji`
```

Please, don't forget to add in tags the database you're using, **SQL is not a database**, is a programming language.